# Using C# and regex to find a whole word in a list of strings, and then replacing only that word

Tags: c#, regex

Good day people...
i need to find a way, with c# and regex expressions, firstly, to find a word, lets call it search, in a list of strings.
example of list of strings:I have many lists of lists of strings;, this is only one list with 4 strings:

```
 {"   port MegaModuleRefitLogEventMegaModuleRefitLogEvent.REFIT_FINISHED,moduleId,id,ActionJSON.encodeJSONanalyticExport,ActionJSON.encodeJSON_pendingDesign.analyticExport,ActionJSON.port.encodeJSON_pendingDesign.analyticExportthis;",

    "private static var _warReportManager:WarReportManager = new WarReportManager.port;",
"import com.waterworld.managers.warreport.WarReportManager;",
"else iflastBattleReport.report != port && lastBattleReport.port"}
```

now, my search is "port"
firstly, i used:

```
string search="port"
if (myStrList.Any(str => str.Contains(search)))
{
//go to the funtion that does the actual replacing etc
}
```

to find it...tho, my expression finds ALL lists that contains the search...the invalid scenarios included...

This given list contains 4 strings in the example...all 5 got more than one occurrence of "port", in various forms.
my string lists sometimes have many occurrences, other times none...but its a list.
acceptable occurrences i need to find with above expression:
on the first string of the list:

1. "  port " without the white spaces in the beginning is valid;
2. ".port." without the "." is valid..."." can be a .",:'[]{}<>;
3. all other occurrences in first string is not valid.

on the second string of the list:
 - 
 - ".port;" is valid without the "." and ";"

on the third string:

- no valid occurrences.

on the fourth string:

1. "!= port &&" is valid without "!= " and " &&"
2. ".port" is valid...without "."and the last character might be null.

then once i fount the valid strings containing the search...
i need to do some functions with them..one of which is replace the given word say with "myport"
note..all searches // replaces is case sensitive.

```
string pattern = @"\b"+search+@"\b";
string replace = "myport";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
```

tho,this only does the ones where the boundaries are white space...not the other scenarios...
any help will be valued.
I have looked around, and most of these whole word scenarios are white space specific, tho..there might be an answer to my situation on here...
regards

EDIT.
thanks to @jdweng

for the search i did as follow:

```
string pattern = string.Format(@"[\s]+{0}[\s.!?$]+", search);

                            Regex matcher = new Regex(pattern);

                            if (teslist.Any(str => matcher.IsMatch(str)))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("string match found: "");
                            }
```

EDIT 2...
tho jdweng's answer is close..its not the required result...
ive tried to put the requirements as follow:
the search pattern:

- may begin after white space,
- may begin after these characters ,.<>;:'"{}[]\?/-_+=()
- may be in beginning of line
- must contain only search string
- may not be part of beginning of word with alpha numerical
- BUT
- may not be part of end part of word
- may end before white space,
- may end before ,.<>;:'"{}[]\?/-_+=()
- may be at the end of the line

jdweng's answer did nit include all of the options..and...it replaced the search including those start or end characters, where-as, i only need to replace the given search string.

Comment: @jdweng thanks on your answer, ive added the search part..looks good, regards :)  
not sure why the down-vote...but..oh-well :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code below works. I replaced \b to get any white space. And put into square bracket with a plus to get multiple occurrences. At end did similar and included periods, exclamation marks and question marks which can occur at end of sentenc :

```
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "   port MegaModuleRefitLogEventMegaModuleRefitLogEvent.REFIT_FINISHED,moduleId,id,ActionJSON.encodeJSONanalyticExport,ActionJSON.encodeJSON_pendingDesign.analyticExport,ActionJSON.port.encodeJSON_pendingDesign.analyticExportthis;",
                                  "private static var _warReportManager:WarReportManager = new WarReportManager.port;",
                                  "import com.waterworld.managers.warreport.WarReportManager;",
                                  "else iflastBattleReport.report != port && lastBattleReport.port"};

            string findWord = "port";
            string pattern = string.Format("(?'prefix'[\\s.]+)(?'word'{0})((?'suffix'[\\s.!?;]+)|(?'suffix'$))", findWord);

            string replace = "myport";
            string replacePattern = string.Format("${{prefix}}{0}${{suffix}}", replace);

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacePattern);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: thanks a lot :)
how would i got to work in an List<List<string>> environment to filter out first which list contains the regex patern?

Comment: almost there...only minor issue ive found on this...example:
"WarReportManager.port;" needs to be replaced as :"WarReportManager.myport;"  , but instead i get :"WarReportManagermyport"

Comment: I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok..firstly, for filtering the possible matchc lists out...to see if thers a match in a list...i did:

```
string pattern = string.Format(@"[\W\s\b]{0}[\b\s\W]", search);

Regex matcher = new Regex(pattern);

if (teslist.Any(sTrr => matcher.IsMatch(sTrr)))
 {
      Console.WriteLine("search found for list");
        //....do stuff
     }
```

then..on the replacing section..i had to create a list of the regex matches on the pattern, and replace each match separately...

```
string pattern = string.Format(@"[\W\s\b]{0}[\b\s\W]", search);
    Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> MatchList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
    foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(str))
         {
            string myMatch = ItemMatch.ToString();
            string myReplace = (ItemMatch.ToString().Replace(read, replace));
            KeyValuePair<string, string> ThisPair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(myMatch, myReplace);
            MatchList.Add(ThisPair);
          }
     string newValue = str;
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> KVstr in MatchList)
           {
               newValue = (str.Replace(KVstr.Key, KVstr.Value));
            }
     Console.WriteLine("str: " + str);
     Console.WriteLine(" newValue: " + newValue);
```